# Loading a txt file, then turning it into an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to load a .txt file in php and then turn the data into an array for use labeleing photos. Specifically, I want a text file that will contain a number of photo titles and captions that I can then dynamically address to label my photos. Here's what I have thus far, which is working just fine but is not creating an array that I understand. When it returns "$arrM[1]", it's returning the first item in every line of my text file rather than just the first item.

```
    $f = fopen("set_data.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($f)) { 
        $arrM = explode(",",fgets($f)); 
        echo $arrM[1]; 
    }
    fclose($f);
```

and my text file looks like this:

```
title a, caption a
title b, caption b
title c, caption c
```

So, my questions are:

1. How do I format my txt file so that the items will be uniquely addressable? I don't understand the difference between a line break and a comma (or any other symbol that can act as a delimiter). Nothing online is helping make this clear.
2. How do I explode the txt file into an array? Ideally I want to be able to retrieve "title a" or "caption b" all alone and based on a variable (such as "$arrM[i]), but it's not creating the array that way. I need to be able to address both the number of the array entry as well as the part of the array. So, in plain language, I need to be able to address it as "Array entry number two, show me the second item".

Any ideas?

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/fgetcsv

Comment: You need to create an array, like Putr said: You use $data[], so every explode creates a new element and you can access it with $data[0][0] = (element before ,) and $data[0][1] (element after ,)...
Learn about foreach or count

Answer (score 2):

It's returning all the titles because you have the echo in a while loop.

You can do this:

```
 $data = array();
 $f = fopen("set_data.txt", "r");
 while (!feof($f)) { 
      $data[] = explode(",",fgets($f));     
 }
 fclose($f);
 var_dump($data);
```

**Line break** is a special character that creates a new line. This can be the

- `\n` Newline character (Unix)
- `\r` Carriage return character
- `\n\r` Newline+ carriage return character

To help with the mess there is PHP_EOL (php constant).

A **delimiter** is the limit character that is used when creating sub-strings from a **string**.